# Generate copynumber graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate a copynumber graph using R ggplot2 package. The code is

```
ggplot(HG01872_CHEK2, aes(start,cn)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cn)),size=2) +
ylim(0, 4) +
labs(title="CHEK2", x="Coordenadas", y="Copy_Number") +
scale_colour_manual(name = "Copy_Number", labels=c("CN 1", "CN 2", "CN 3"), values = c("red","black","blue")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

As a results, I got the following image.

[image: Copynumber gain]

What I need is to set colors to specific counts. So, y.axis values 0 and 1 = Red, 2 = black, 3 and 4 = blue. The code above is setting only two colors: red for the smallest value and black for the highest! Can someone help me on this issue? Thanks

Data is

```
chrom start    end      gene   log2       cn depth   weight
chr22 29083874 29083984 CHEK2  0.17003500  2 511.564 0.615555
chr22 29085112 29085213 CHEK2  0.15208400  2 360.455 0.576626
chr22 29090009 29090115 CHEK2  0.08881250  2 415.557 0.597564
chr22 29091104 29091240 CHEK2 -0.11787200  2 518.022 0.592463
chr22 29091687 29091871 CHEK2  0.17912200  2 282.495 0.595016
chr22 29092878 29092985 CHEK2  0.00317544  2 262.346 0.567219
chr22 29095815 29095935 CHEK2  0.18198100  2 352.750 0.553413
chr22 29099482 29099564 CHEK2  0.08844700  2 334.073 0.525487
chr22 29105983 29106057 CHEK2 -0.18492700  2 274.649 0.495355
chr22 29107886 29108015 CHEK2  0.04725930  2 704.922 0.568923
chr22 29115372 29115483 CHEK2  0.48394000  3 629.802 0.544551
chr22 29120954 29121122 CHEK2  0.53955500  3 877.000 0.636210
chr22 29121220 29121365 CHEK2  0.50475400  3 790.517 0.635871
chr22 29126397 29126546 CHEK2  0.67394400  3 345.356 0.467572
chr22 29130380 29130719 CHEK2  0.04980090  2 629.979 0.873423
```

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput()` so we can help, but it's because you only have 2 values total for `cn` according to your graph. If you want to adjust the colors to specific y-axis values, you can try `values = c("0" = "red", "1" = "red", "2" = "black", "3" = "blue", "3" = "blue")`

Comment: Are there in fact cases whith `cn` > 2? You can check with `table(HG01872_CHEK2$cn)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the data... It's in the description now!

Comment: @caldwellst when I try what you just told, I got the following error: "Warning message: Removed 15 rows containing missing values (geom_point)". Just got a blank graph!

Comment: @caldwellst, actually worked! I was typing a few wrong arguments... Thanks for your help!